# Request level monitoring for hystrix stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix, netflix, hystrix-dashboard

Does hystrix support request level monitoring.

For example, I have certain types of requests which I send to a single external API.

**Request A : CITY REQUEST | Request B : COUNTRY REQUEST  | Request C : GLOBAL REQUEST**

I want to monitor these types of requests separately on my dashboard and I don't want to create separate services/methods and annotate them separately with different command keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Realized that it can't be solved by using annotations currently. Created a HystrixCommand for the same and added conditions on CommandKey string.